# polymer and bootstrap integration

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, polymer

I am trying to use bootstrap for the scaffolfing of a polymer paper shadowed element like this

```
<div class="card" style="padding:20px; max-width:200px;">
  <paper-shadow z="1">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4"><paper-fab class="mini"></paper-fab></div>
     <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Test card</h2></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
    <p>test body</p>
     </div>
    <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
    </div>
  </paper-shadow>
</div>
```

But I am not getting the desired result. Whay am I missing?

Comment: What are you getting and what is the desired result??

Comment: I'd like to have the fab at the left side of the card header (col-4) and the h2 at the right side of it (col-8).